# How to connect to MySql via LDAP (without putting a username and password)

Tags: mysql

I want to connect to a MySql server using the following example of a connection string:
"Server=server_name;Port=3306;database=db_name"

My code is accessing from a container using the username that runs the container/pod (Kubernetes) itself.
Meaning that I don't want to use this connection string example:
"Server=server_name;Port=3306;database=db_name;user=user_name;password=my_pwd"

All I need is to connect with the user running the service (this user is an Active Directory user).
How can I do that?